# How to specify U-Boot not to use uramdisk

Tags: linux-kernel, u-boot, ramdisk

I would like to specify U-Boot not to use uramdisk to boot because my ramdisk is part of the Linux image. The problem is that even if I choose sdboot which I modified and call "bootm {linux} - {devicetree}" it checks for the uramdisk.image.gz file existence.

EDIT : Whatever I do it doesn't override sdboot property. It's like it is loading my uEnv.txt (and it works because it correctly takes my device tree blob which has a different name) and just after that it overrides the sdboot property...

Here is my uEnv.txt file :

```
sdboot=if mmcinfo; then run uenvboot; echo Copying Linux from SD to RAM... && load mmc 0 ${kernel_load_address} ${kernel_image} && echo Copying Device Tree from SD to RAM... && load mmc 0 ${devicetree_load_address} ${devicetree_image} && echo Boot Linux kernel... &&bootm ${kernel_load_address} - ${devicetree_load_address}; fi
```

And here is the log I get :

```
U-Boot 2015.07-svn563 (Nov 17 2016 - 17:10:38 +0100)

Model: Zynq ZC702 Development Board
I2C:   ready
DRAM:  ECC disabled 512 MiB
# Malloc address : 0x1F316000
# Malloc size    : 12713984 (0x00c20000)
# CONFIG_SYS_TEXT_BASE       : 0x04000000
# U-Boot relocated in RAM at : 0x1ff36000
MMC:   zynq_sdhci: 0
SF: Detected N25Q128 with page size 256 Bytes, erase size 64 KiB, total 16 MiB
*** Warning - bad CRC, using default environment

# load_addr = 0x00000000
In:    serial
Out:   serial
Err:   serial
Model: Zynq ZC702 Development Board
Net:   Gem.e000b000
Hit any key to stop autoboot:  0 
Device: zynq_sdhci
Manufacturer ID: 3
OEM: 5344
Name: SE32G 
Tran Speed: 50000000
Rd Block Len: 512
SD version 3.0
High Capacity: Yes
Capacity: 29.7 GiB
Bus Width: 4-bit
Erase Group Size: 512 Bytes
reading uEnv.txt
2187 bytes read in 14 ms (152.3 KiB/s)
Loaded environment from uEnv.txt
Importing environment from SD ...
Copying Linux from SD to RAM...
reading busybox.img
11904111 bytes read in 1003 ms (11.3 MiB/s)
reading mlg-x.dtb
13851 bytes read in 15 ms (901.4 KiB/s)
reading uramdisk.image.gz
** Unable to read file uramdisk.image.gz **
zynq-uboot>
```

Here is the full trace if I let the autoboot fail with uramdisk, then printenv, then reset default env and printenv again :

```
U-Boot 2015.07-svn563 (Nov 17 2016 - 17:10:38 +0100)

Model: Zynq ZC702 Development Board
I2C:   ready
DRAM:  ECC disabled 512 MiB
# Malloc address : 0x1F316000
# Malloc size    : 12713984 (0x00c20000)
# CONFIG_SYS_TEXT_BASE       : 0x04000000
# U-Boot relocated in RAM at : 0x1ff36000
MMC:   zynq_sdhci: 0
SF: Detected N25Q128 with page size 256 Bytes, erase size 64 KiB, total 16 MiB
*** Warning - bad CRC, using default environment

# load_addr = 0x00000000
In:    serial
Out:   serial
Err:   serial
Model: Zynq ZC702 Development Board
Net:   Gem.e000b000
Hit any key to stop autoboot:  0 
Device: zynq_sdhci
Manufacturer ID: 3
OEM: 5344
Name: SE32G 
Tran Speed: 50000000
Rd Block Len: 512
SD version 3.0
High Capacity: Yes
Capacity: 29.7 GiB
Bus Width: 4-bit
Erase Group Size: 512 Bytes
reading uEnv.txt
381 bytes read in 10 ms (37.1 KiB/s)
Loaded environment from uEnv.txt
Importing environment from SD ...
Copying Linux from SD to RAM...
reading busybox.img
11904111 bytes read in 1004 ms (11.3 MiB/s)
reading mlg-x.dtb
13839 bytes read in 15 ms (900.4 KiB/s)
reading uramdisk.image.gz
** Unable to read file uramdisk.image.gz **
zynq-uboot> printenv 
baudrate=115200
bitstream_image=system.bit.bin
boot_image=BOOT.bin
boot_size=0xF00000
bootcmd=run $modeboot
bootdelay=3
bootenv=uEnv.txt
devicetree_image=mlg-x.dtb
devicetree_load_address=0x2000000
devicetree_size=0x20000
dfu_mmc=run dfu_mmc_info && dfu 0 mmc 0
dfu_mmc_info=set dfu_alt_info ${kernel_image} fat 0 1\\;${devicetree_image} fat 0 1\\;${ramdisk_image} fat 0 1
dfu_ram=run dfu_ram_info && dfu 0 ram 0
dfu_ram_info=set dfu_alt_info ${kernel_image} ram 0x3000000 0x500000\\;${devicetree_image} ram 0x2A00000 0x20000\\;${ramdisk_image} ram 0x2000000 0x600000
ethact=Gem.e000b000
ethaddr=00:0a:35:00:01:22
fdt_high=0x20000000
filesize=360f
importbootenv=echo Importing environment from SD ...; env import -t ${loadbootenv_addr} $filesize
initrd_high=0x20000000
ipaddr=10.10.70.102
jtagboot=echo TFTPing Linux to RAM... && tftpboot ${kernel_load_address} ${kernel_image} && tftpboot ${devicetree_load_address} ${devicetree_image} && tftpboot ${ramdisk_load_address} ${ramdisk_image} && bootm ${kernel_load_address} ${ra
mdisk_load_address} ${devicetree_load_address}
kernel_image=busybox.img
kernel_load_address=0x2080000
kernel_size=0x500000
loadbit_addr=0x100000
loadbootenv=load mmc 0 ${loadbootenv_addr} ${bootenv}
loadbootenv_addr=0x2000000
mmc_loadbit=echo Loading bitstream from SD/MMC/eMMC to RAM.. && mmcinfo && load mmc 0 ${loadbit_addr} ${bitstream_image} && fpga load 0 ${loadbit_addr} ${filesize}
modeboot=sdboot
nandboot=echo Copying Linux from NAND flash to RAM... && nand read ${kernel_load_address} 0x100000 ${kernel_size} && nand read ${devicetree_load_address} 0x600000 ${devicetree_size} && echo Copying ramdisk... && nand read ${ramdisk_load_
address} 0x620000 ${ramdisk_size} && bootm ${kernel_load_address} ${ramdisk_load_address} ${devicetree_load_address}
norboot=echo Copying Linux from NOR flash to RAM... && cp.b 0xE2100000 ${kernel_load_address} ${kernel_size} && cp.b 0xE2600000 ${devicetree_load_address} ${devicetree_size} && echo Copying ramdisk... && cp.b 0xE2620000 ${ramdisk_load_ad
dress} ${ramdisk_size} && bootm ${kernel_load_address} ${ramdisk_load_address} ${devicetree_load_address}
preboot=if test $modeboot = sdboot && env run sd_uEnvtxt_existence_test; then if env run loadbootenv; then env run importbootenv; fi; fi; 
qspiboot=echo Copying Linux from QSPI flash to RAM... && sf probe 0 0 0 && sf read ${kernel_load_address} 0x100000 ${kernel_size} && sf read ${devicetree_load_address} 0x600000 ${devicetree_size} && echo Copying ramdisk... && sf read ${r
amdisk_load_address} 0x620000 ${ramdisk_size} && bootm ${kernel_load_address} ${ramdisk_load_address} ${devicetree_load_address}
ramdisk_image=uramdisk.image.gz
ramdisk_load_address=0x4000000
ramdisk_size=0x5E0000
rsa_jtagboot=echo TFTPing Image to RAM... && tftpboot 0x100000 ${boot_image} && zynqrsa 0x100000 && bootm ${kernel_load_address} ${ramdisk_load_address} ${devicetree_load_address}
rsa_nandboot=echo Copying Image from NAND flash to RAM... && nand read 0x100000 0x0 ${boot_size} && zynqrsa 0x100000 && bootm ${kernel_load_address} ${ramdisk_load_address} ${devicetree_load_address}
rsa_norboot=echo Copying Image from NOR flash to RAM... && cp.b 0xE2100000 0x100000 ${boot_size} && zynqrsa 0x100000 && bootm ${kernel_load_address} ${ramdisk_load_address} ${devicetree_load_address}
rsa_qspiboot=echo Copying Image from QSPI flash to RAM... && sf probe 0 0 0 && sf read 0x100000 0x0 ${boot_size} && zynqrsa 0x100000 && bootm ${kernel_load_address} ${ramdisk_load_address} ${devicetree_load_address}
rsa_sdboot=echo Copying Image from SD to RAM... && load mmc 0 0x100000 ${boot_image} && zynqrsa 0x100000 && bootm ${kernel_load_address} ${ramdisk_load_address} ${devicetree_load_address}
sd_uEnvtxt_existence_test=test -e mmc 0 /uEnv.txt
sdboot=if mmcinfo; then run uenvboot; echo Copying Linux from SD to RAM... && load mmc 0 ${kernel_load_address} ${kernel_image} && echo Copying Device Tree from SD to RAM... && load mmc 0 ${devicetree_load_address} ${devicetree_image} &&
 echo Boot Linux kernel... && bootm ${kernel_load_address} - ${devicetree_load_address}; fi
serverip=10.10.70.101
stderr=serial
stdin=serial
stdout=serial
thor_mmc=run dfu_mmc_info && thordown 0 mmc 0
thor_ram=run dfu_ram_info && thordown 0 ram 0
uenvboot=if run loadbootenv; then echo Loaded environment from ${bootenv}; run importbootenv; fi; if test -n $uenvcmd; then echo Running uenvcmd ...; run uenvcmd; fi
usbboot=if usb start; then run uenvboot; echo Copying Linux from USB to RAM... && load usb 0 ${kernel_load_address} ${kernel_image} && load usb 0 ${devicetree_load_address} ${devicetree_image} && load usb 0 ${ramdisk_load_address} ${ramd
isk_image} && bootm ${kernel_load_address} ${ramdisk_load_address} ${devicetree_load_address}; fi

Environment size: 4843/131068 bytes
zynq-uboot> env default -f -a
## Resetting to default environment
zynq-uboot> printenv 
baudrate=115200
bitstream_image=system.bit.bin
boot_image=BOOT.bin
boot_size=0xF00000
bootcmd=run $modeboot
bootdelay=3
bootenv=uEnv.txt
devicetree_image=devicetree.dtb
devicetree_load_address=0x2000000
devicetree_size=0x20000
dfu_mmc=run dfu_mmc_info && dfu 0 mmc 0
dfu_mmc_info=set dfu_alt_info ${kernel_image} fat 0 1\\;${devicetree_image} fat 0 1\\;${ramdisk_image} fat 0 1
dfu_ram=run dfu_ram_info && dfu 0 ram 0
dfu_ram_info=set dfu_alt_info ${kernel_image} ram 0x3000000 0x500000\\;${devicetree_image} ram 0x2A00000 0x20000\\;${ramdisk_image} ram 0x2000000 0x600000
ethaddr=00:0a:35:00:01:22
fdt_high=0x20000000
importbootenv=echo Importing environment from SD ...; env import -t ${loadbootenv_addr} $filesize
initrd_high=0x20000000
ipaddr=10.10.70.102
jtagboot=echo TFTPing Linux to RAM... && tftpboot ${kernel_load_address} ${kernel_image} && tftpboot ${devicetree_load_address} ${devicetree_image} && tftpboot ${ramdisk_load_address} ${ramdisk_image} && bootm ${kernel_load_address} ${ra
mdisk_load_address} ${devicetree_load_address}
kernel_image=uImage
kernel_load_address=0x2080000
kernel_size=0x500000
loadbit_addr=0x100000
loadbootenv=load mmc 0 ${loadbootenv_addr} ${bootenv}
loadbootenv_addr=0x2000000
mmc_loadbit=echo Loading bitstream from SD/MMC/eMMC to RAM.. && mmcinfo && load mmc 0 ${loadbit_addr} ${bitstream_image} && fpga load 0 ${loadbit_addr} ${filesize}
nandboot=echo Copying Linux from NAND flash to RAM... && nand read ${kernel_load_address} 0x100000 ${kernel_size} && nand read ${devicetree_load_address} 0x600000 ${devicetree_size} && echo Copying ramdisk... && nand read ${ramdisk_load_
address} 0x620000 ${ramdisk_size} && bootm ${kernel_load_address} ${ramdisk_load_address} ${devicetree_load_address}
norboot=echo Copying Linux from NOR flash to RAM... && cp.b 0xE2100000 ${kernel_load_address} ${kernel_size} && cp.b 0xE2600000 ${devicetree_load_address} ${devicetree_size} && echo Copying ramdisk... && cp.b 0xE2620000 ${ramdisk_load_ad
dress} ${ramdisk_size} && bootm ${kernel_load_address} ${ramdisk_load_address} ${devicetree_load_address}
preboot=if test $modeboot = sdboot && env run sd_uEnvtxt_existence_test; then if env run loadbootenv; then env run importbootenv; fi; fi; 
qspiboot=echo Copying Linux from QSPI flash to RAM... && sf probe 0 0 0 && sf read ${kernel_load_address} 0x100000 ${kernel_size} && sf read ${devicetree_load_address} 0x600000 ${devicetree_size} && echo Copying ramdisk... && sf read ${r
amdisk_load_address} 0x620000 ${ramdisk_size} && bootm ${kernel_load_address} ${ramdisk_load_address} ${devicetree_load_address}
ramdisk_image=uramdisk.image.gz
ramdisk_load_address=0x4000000
ramdisk_size=0x5E0000
rsa_jtagboot=echo TFTPing Image to RAM... && tftpboot 0x100000 ${boot_image} && zynqrsa 0x100000 && bootm ${kernel_load_address} ${ramdisk_load_address} ${devicetree_load_address}
rsa_nandboot=echo Copying Image from NAND flash to RAM... && nand read 0x100000 0x0 ${boot_size} && zynqrsa 0x100000 && bootm ${kernel_load_address} ${ramdisk_load_address} ${devicetree_load_address}
rsa_norboot=echo Copying Image from NOR flash to RAM... && cp.b 0xE2100000 0x100000 ${boot_size} && zynqrsa 0x100000 && bootm ${kernel_load_address} ${ramdisk_load_address} ${devicetree_load_address}
rsa_qspiboot=echo Copying Image from QSPI flash to RAM... && sf probe 0 0 0 && sf read 0x100000 0x0 ${boot_size} && zynqrsa 0x100000 && bootm ${kernel_load_address} ${ramdisk_load_address} ${devicetree_load_address}
rsa_sdboot=echo Copying Image from SD to RAM... && load mmc 0 0x100000 ${boot_image} && zynqrsa 0x100000 && bootm ${kernel_load_address} ${ramdisk_load_address} ${devicetree_load_address}
sd_uEnvtxt_existence_test=test -e mmc 0 /uEnv.txt
sdboot=if mmcinfo; then run uenvboot; echo Copying Linux from SD to RAM... && load mmc 0 ${kernel_load_address} ${kernel_image} && load mmc 0 ${devicetree_load_address} ${devicetree_image} && load mmc 0 ${ramdisk_load_address} ${ramdisk_
image} && bootm ${kernel_load_address} ${ramdisk_load_address} ${devicetree_load_address}; fi
serverip=10.10.70.101
thor_mmc=run dfu_mmc_info && thordown 0 mmc 0
thor_ram=run dfu_ram_info && thordown 0 ram 0
uenvboot=if run loadbootenv; then echo Loaded environment from ${bootenv}; run importbootenv; fi; if test -n $uenvcmd; then echo Running uenvcmd ...; run uenvcmd; fi
usbboot=if usb start; then run uenvboot; echo Copying Linux from USB to RAM... && load usb 0 ${kernel_load_address} ${kernel_image} && load usb 0 ${devicetree_load_address} ${devicetree_image} && load usb 0 ${ramdisk_load_address} ${ramd
isk_image} && bootm ${kernel_load_address} ${ramdisk_load_address} ${devicetree_load_address}; fi

Environment size: 4742/131068 bytes
zynq-uboot>
```

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that it is not running the `sdboot` that is in `uEnv.txt` but rather the `sdboot` that is in the default environment.

Evidence of this is that you don't see `Copying Device Tree from SD to RAM...` in your log output.

Try adding something like the following at the end of `uEnv.txt`:

```
uenvcmd=echo Copying Linux from SD to RAM... && load mmc 0 ${kernel_load_address} ${kernel_image} && echo Copying Device Tree from SD to RAM... && load mmc 0 ${devicetree_load_address} ${devicetree_image} && echo Boot Linux kernel... && bootm ${kernel_load_address} - ${devicetree_load_address}
```

I can't test this of course - but you should see the following in your log:

```
Running uenvcmd ...
Copying Linux from SD to RAM...
...
Copying Device Tree from SD to RAM...
...
Boot Linux kernel...
...
```

Good luck!

Comment: I will test it right away, but how u-boot will run this command ? Is it a u-boot default command ?

Comment: Remember that I am guessing ... but it looks like it can't load an environment so it uses the default environment compiled into u-boot and runs the `sdboot` from that, which will probably look similar to your `sdboot` and so the first thing it does is reinitialise the environment from `uEnv.txt`. The result is that if you want to change things, the changes have to be in any env var other than `sdboot`.

Comment: I hit return by accident, then ran into the stupid 5 min limit ... I meant to add that you need to find a place to put your changes that is executed *after* the env has been imported from `uEnv.txt`, but you can't use `sdboot` or `uenvboot` ... it appears that is what `uenvcmd` is for.

Comment: So yes uenvcmd works like you said if I use "run uenvcmd" (and my custom sdboot works as well). But when I try to run "run uenvboot" I get an error calling "if test -n $uenvcmd;" which prints the help of the test command "usage: test [args..] blabla..."

Comment: Put quotes around `$uenvcmd` e.g. `"$uenvcmd"`

Comment: Also, you want this to work on power-on, not just from typing the commands.

Comment: To answer your question, `uenvcmd` is run by `uenvboot` after it has loaded the environment from `uEnv.txt`. The default `sdboot` will run `uenvboot` before doing anything else. If it works the way I think it does, then the call to `uenvboot` in the default `sdboot` will never return, because it will have booted Linux via `uenvcmd`.

Comment: I don't know why but everything I change in my uenv.txt has no effect, it still take the default uEnv... Autoboot fails because I have no ramdisk, after that I get the console prompt and if I try "run bootcmd" averything works well... So the problem lies in the uenv loading I think... Why printing "reading uEnv.txt" and not load it ?...

Comment: find out what the compiled in default environment is and post it here ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48734/discussion-between-awax-and-murray-jensen).

Comment: I edited the post to add the full trace with default env at the end